# PhpStorm tells me: "Namespace name doesn't match PSR 0/PSR 4 project structure"

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and everything works fine.

However, I keep getting these warning messages. I have looked at the JetBrains docs, but I remain a bit foggy what to do about it.

Essentially, I am concerned that if I allow PhpStorm to automatically run "Detect PSR0 Namespace Roots" then it could break my code / project.

Not sure what is going on, what should I do?

Comment: PSR-0 -- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/ ; PSR-4 -- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you use `composer` the more recent answer to synchronize with `composer` is a better option.

---

PSR-4 namespace roots can specify a prefix which can be configured.

Here is the process:

1. Find the root of your namespace e.g `src`.
2. <kbd>right click</kbd> Mark Directory as Sources Root.
3. Menu -> File -> Settings -> Directories.
4. Click the pencil icon or p^ next to your Sources Root.
5. Enter the namespace prefix.

See [PHPStorm configuring PHP namespaces](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-php-namespaces-in-a-project.html)

Comment: I've been using PHPStorm for many years and never knew about this tip, thank you! BTW, for anyone reading, `p^` I think means `Pencil icon`

Comment: As stated above `p^` is the `Pencil icon`. Morover, if: your namespace is `Foo\Bar`; class is `Baz`; and the file containing it `src\Baz.php`, then in the popup window put `\Foo\Bar`.

Comment: Well done. I just wonder why it's not being read from composer.json (definitions in "autoload" and "autoload-dev" sections). Edit: it can be synchronized - check out other answer by @Mexidense

Answer (score 76):

Easier than the last answers:

[image: PHPStorm & Composer settings]

Go to the Settings windows: Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Composer and then, enable Sync IDE settings with composer.json in order to load the PSR-0 & PSR-4 set up.

PS: PhpStorm 2020.3.2 (Build #PS-203.7148.74, built on January 27, 2021)

I hope it's useful to everyone!

Comment: Thank you! Was driving me nuts

Comment: Please note that if your path to composer.json was empty, it can take an enormous time to reindex files if your project is big. It took my PhpStorm something like 30 minutes before I could interact with it again. Let it finish its job.

Answer (score 5):

In Addtition to Mexidense great answer
As it just happened to me, if you have the Synchronization already activated, that warning may show up.
Deactivate the Synchronization, <kbd>apply</kbd> it and reactivate it (and <kbd>apply</kbd> it)

Comment: Can't do. It's activated AND grayed out, meaning I cannot deactivate it.

Answer (score 1):

I already had IDE settings synchronization with composer.json enabled, I just had to trigger it.

The quickest way is probably to:

1. Modify `autoload -> psr-4` section of my `composer.json` to something else:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/asdfasdf"
        }
    },
```

2. Open a php source file in editor, see namespace warning highlighted
3. Modify it back

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

4. Navigate back to the php source file, see the warning go away

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my Symfony 4 to Symfony 5 with a fresh composer install I suddenly got this warning.

What fixed it for me was a simple cache reset in PHPStorm:

**File -> Invalidate caches -> Invalidate and restart**

Answer (score -4):

PSR-0 is just a convention for structuring your PHP projects. When PHPStorm asks to automatically "Detect PSR0 Namespace Roots", it is offering to check which classes will be autoloaded so it can perform correct auto-completion while you write your code.

It does not affect your code, but it may improve your coding experience.